# Condition evaluating to type mismatch on empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that searches a large table of data to find a row that satisfies several conditions and take some values from it. Sometimes there will be no row to find and in such cases I want my values to be 0. The algorithm I use is:

```
row = 2

Do Until (row satisfies cond1 And cond2 And cond 3) Or Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    row = row + 1
Loop

If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
    myval = 0
Else
    myval = something taken from row
End If
```

I get a problem whenever one of my conditions evaluates to type mismatch when tested on an empty row* - if no row is found and the code arrives at the end, I get an error and the macro never checks that it indeed is at the end of the data.

*Example: one of my conditions tests a Date variable against a date stored as text, so I use `mydate = Datevalue(text in row)` to test and this leads to type mismatch if text is empty.

Do you know a simple solution to this problem? The easiest thing I can think of is calculating number of rows before and switching to a `For` loop, but this definitely will add some extra variables and calculations.

Comment: You should post the full code including the logic for `cond1`, `cond2` and `cond3`

Comment: The exact conditions have nothing to do with my question and including them would clutter up the code a lot, so I decided to leave them out and include an example instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go :

```
row = 2

Do Until Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    If (row satisfies cond1 And cond2 And cond 3) Then Exit Do
    row = row + 1
Loop

If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
    myval = 0
Else
    myval = something taken from row
End If
```

So basically, loop until you get to the end of the table, but break out of the loop if you find an appropriate value.